# NSButton bezelColor

Tags: macos, cocoa

What appearances of NSButton support `bezelColor` instance property?

I'm asking because I would like to style some button with color to differentiate them.

Thanks

Comment: `NSButton` has a lot of cruft in it.  I'm not sure it actually does anything at all nowadays.  You might want to create a custom button cell class in which you can draw whatever content you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using macOS 11 or newer, you can use the `bezelColor` property when using a button with `bezelStyle` set to `.rounded` or `regularSquare` in code, or button style set to 'Push' or 'Bezel' when using the interface designer in Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

As of 10.12.1, the only place where this property has any effect is within the Touch Bar appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a `NSButton` subclass called `FlatButton` that makes it super-easy to change button background color, text color, icon color, borders and other types of styling, from Interface Builder:

https://github.com/OskarGroth/FlatButton

It should provide the functionality you are asking for.

[image: FlatButton for macOS]